# Excel return 0 instead correct result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a big excel document with this two columns:

[image]

I have to extract the minimum value from price column for every distinct product: for example, if I select the first product, there will be a function returns me 0,91.

For do this I have this formula: =MIN(IF(E:E=Ex;F:F)) where x is the row number. Then the formula returns me 0, but if I control it

[image]

the result is correct!

P.S. For not-italian people SE means IF and FALSO means FALSE

Comment: This is an array formula and must be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array formula and the correct syntax is

```
=MIN(IF(E:E=E2;F:F))
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If you dont want an array formula, usee `AGGREAGTE`:

```
=AGGREGATE(15; 6; $F$1:$F$999/($E$1:$E$999=E2); 1)
```

In both cases, **avoid full columns** when working with arrays.